# InvalidOperationException in LINQPad query against SQLite database

Tags: linq, linqpad

I have the following LINQ query in an application. The data source is a `List<Borehole>` constructed in memory for testing purposes.

```
var lq = from p in data
         group p by p.CostCenter into g
         select new {  CostCenter = g.Key, 
                       AverageDepth = g.Average(p => p.OriginalDepth),
                       NullDepthCount = g.Count(p => p.OriginalDepth == null) };
```

It runs perfectly and gives the desired selection result. However, when I run the following query in LINQPad, it results in `InvalidOperationException`:

```
var lq = from p in Boreholes
          group p by p.CostCenter into g
          select new {  CostCenter = g.Key, 
                        AverageDepth = g.Average(p => p.OriginalDepth),
                        NullDepthCount = g.Count(p => p.OriginalDepth == null) };
```

Here the data source is a table in a SQLite database, linked to LINQPad using the IQ 2.0.5.0 LINQPad driver. The error message is:

`No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.`

I'm using `LINQPad v4.42.01`. The application sample is compiled vs `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile`.

The `OriginalDepth` property is of type `double?`.

Why is my query not working in LINQPad / why is it working in my application?

What can I do to fix the LINQPad query?

**UPDATE**

If I copy and paste my application code, including the definition of the dummy `Borehole` class and the creation of the dummy `data` list, into LINQPad, it works fine. Thus the issue is not that LINQPad rejects a query format that works in an application.

*The question becomes:* Why can I use `g.Count(p => p.OriginalDepth == null)` on a `List<Borehole>` object, but when I do the same query on the SQLite table accessed by LINQPad, I get `InvalidOperationException` as described above?

**UPDATE 2**

It doesn't matter what the predicate for the `g.count` part of the query is. The following results in the same error, when executed against the SQLite database table:

```
var lq2 = from p in Boreholes
          group p by p.CostCenter into g
          select new { NullDepthCount = g.Count(p => true )};
```

Comment: are you sure that data (query 1) == Boreholes (query 2)?

Comment: No they are not the same, the one is just a dummy with manually created objects in, the other is the actual SQLite Database contents, and the classes are thus automatically created by LINQPad. The question is why the operation is permitted on the `List<Borehole>` but not on the table accessed by LINQPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every Linq provider is going to support every feature, so presumably you have hit on one here that the IQ provider does not support.

If the size of the table is small (and sqlite databases usually are) then you can do

```
var lq = from p in Boreholes.ToList()
      group p by p.CostCenter into g
      select new {  CostCenter = g.Key, 
                    AverageDepth = g.Average(p => p.OriginalDepth),
                    NullDepthCount = g.Count(p => p.OriginalDepth == null) };
```

Obviously this loads the whole of the boreholes table into memory and hence the query is now a Linq To objects query which then works.

Update.

It would also appear that simply replacing

```
   NullDepthCount = g.Count(p => p.OriginalDepth == null)
```

in your original query which

```
   NullDepthCount = g.Where(p => p.OriginalDepth == null).Count()
```

will work which means you don't need to bring the data into memory.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, the `g.Where().Count()` workaround is perfect, and I'll remember the `.ToList()` trick if I ever run into something similiar.